# Google Add-on script throws server error when calling DriveApp getFolderById or getFileById

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-script-addon, server-error

I have deployed a spreadsheet bound script as an add-on.
It worked when it was container bound.
But now, as an add-on, I get a server error when I call DriveApp.getFolderById

```
function makeMap (){
console.log("start lesmap");
try{var map=DriveApp.getFolderById(DIPmapId); }catch(e){console.log("error map:"+e )}
try{var temp=DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);}catch(e){console.log("error tempfile:"+e) }
}
```

throws errors (in Dutch but meaning: server error, wait a while and try again):

2020-05-23 12:10:11.310 CEST
error map:Exception: Er is helaas een serverfout opgetreden. Wacht enige tijd en probeer het dan nogmaals.
2020-05-23 12:10:11.347 CEST
error tempfile:Exception: Er is helaas een serverfout opgetreden. Wacht enige tijd en probeer het dan nogmaals.

In the manifest file:

```
{
"timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
"dependencies": {
},
"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
"oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
]
}
```

In the G Suite Marketplace SDK Configuration
OAuth 2.0-scopes

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

I have it installed and enabled in the spreadsheet.
I run the function in the add-on menu in the spreadsheet, so I guess this is in authmode full?
I have editor rights on the map and the file in Drive.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is `DIPmapId` coming from? Do users put their own folder Id? Does the code work from Apps Script?

Comment: DIPmapId is a hardcoded variable in the Apps Script.  So users all use the same folder id.

Comment: I also encounter the same issue and i did exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This seems to be a** [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/150633373). You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the bug. Even thought the bug mentions App Maker, it's also an issue with recent deployments.

A possible workaround would be enabling the Drive API (even thought DriveApp and Drive API are not the same) in the [Google Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). After a successful run, you can disable the Drive API again.

Comment: Ty Jescanellas, the workaround did make the script to execute.  I first had to authorize https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents as well but after that ... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by enabling Google Drive API in the Google Cloud Platform:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/metrics