# Can't solve Google File Picker ScriptError on server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth

I was following this step-by-step  about [File Dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) from Google developers Apps Script pages to insert a Google file picker dialog window into my add-on but I keep facing the same error:

***ScriptError: Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.***

I have triple-checked all the steps, key, credentials, scopes in the manifest, and so on and the issue persists. I even looked into this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgGC2y6qJCM) for some light. No need to say I waited "a bit" and tried countless times. What else might be causing this problem?

Comment: Can you share more information on when the error happens? This error looks like a call has failed, have you though of using [Exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) to retry the call that is failing if that is the case?

Comment: @Kessy There's really not much left to share. I'm just following the tutorial and the error shows when I click to load the file picker window. So instead of the UI I get the error message

Comment: Can you share the script you are using, have you managed to check where is the issue exactly appearing? It could be that the issue is from another part of the add-on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Add-on script throws server error when calling DriveApp getFolderById or getFileById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61970960/google-add-on-script-throws-server-error-when-calling-driveapp-getfolderbyid-or)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the file picker and also used the [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#code.gs_2) on the google homepage.

Try to call "DriveApp.getFileById(). If that results in the same error message, the method below should work.

There seems to be a bug within Google Apps script. You have to enable "Google Drive API" in your Google Cloud Platform Project. Then start the File Picker. Afterwards you may disable "Google Drive API" again.

For more information see [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61970960/google-add-on-script-throws-server-error-when-calling-driveapp-getfolderbyid-or), that's where I found the method.